# MVC3: EF Code First and authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, authentication, code-first

I'm building a MVC3 EF Code First application on an SQLExpress DB. It is very important to me that databases are auto-generated whenever the schema changes or something like that.  Now I am adding authentication to my application, and I looked into the Authentication framework that comes with MVC. However, as it appears it requires me to run aspnet_regsql.exe every time a new database is generated. I really need the Authentication tables to be in the same database as my application database.

I'm basically wondering what my options are;

- Is it possible to use the authentication framework and have it auto generated in the same way as the Entity framework generates my other data?
- If not it would be ok for me to write my own authentication, however are there still parts that I can use? in other words, do I need to write a custom membership provider or anything like that? I would like to keep using the attributes [authenticate] etc.

I could use some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with [CodeFirst Membership Provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/)
 - which is a custom provider based on code first - and expand on that if needed (also read through the recommended use on the site).

The above is IMO the best way as you can really integrate the two (and e.g. in case you might need to access e.g. the membership tables directly, relate to your own user/client tables etc.).

But also you have other options...

a) writing an own Db initializer and Seed-ing the database (like what's suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5462981/417747. note: you can utilize different approaches, from running aspnet tables SQL script to creating model for aspnet tables etc.) or

b) use Db initializer which 'preserves' the database - and prepare the database first using aspnet tables

c) (last but not least) use migrations (as rightly suggested by @Chris). Migrations are pretty powerful. You could run `Update-Database -Script` to generate SQL instead of changing the Db - then combine that (with aspnet script or seed-ed db) and use it for creating or updating the db. Migrations require some learning but again is well worth the effort for anything more complex.

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can override the seed method of your DbMigrationsConfiguration or create a migration.

You should then be able to execute the SQL that can be generated from aspnet_regsql.exe or execute aspnet_regsql.exe providing you have permission.

UPDATE 1:

I ended up doing as follows:

```
Add-Migration AspNetRegSql

public partial class AspNetRegSql : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Migrate(false);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Migrate(true);
    }

    private static void Migrate(bool down)
    {
        var action = down ? "R" : "A";
        var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataContext"];
        var arguments = string.Format(@"-Q -C ""{0}"" -{1} mrp", connectionstring, action);

        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace(@"file:\", string.Empty),
            FileName = "aspnet_regsql.exe",
            Arguments = arguments,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        using (var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Then added "aspnet_regsql.exe" to my project and changed build action to "Copy if newer".

UPDATE 2:

I was not aware of the library that NSGaga posted - I  have not looked at it but would recommend you also consider it.

UPDATE 3:

Some useful links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229654.aspx

Comment: looks good as well - maybe this is just better off placed in the 'Seed', i.e. when creating the db first time (or migration has to be an initial one) - and because of the possible permissions problems (I haven't tried this but seems as a very good scenario for e.g. running custom batch files, and more general) - i.e. it's easier controlling it form the Seed - than from e.g. the PM console as this is usually initiated from with PM (frankly I have no idea how that might pan out in certain cases - though probably should work - I usually run VS as admin so likely not going to see any issues).