# Keep Database Content On Model Change

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Using the code-first approach available in the new 4.1 RC.

Is there any way to persist the current data stored in a database when the mode changes? The database is created by the entity framework, and usually the database is dropped and recreated on model changes.

Obviously as soon as the model is changed it will not be possible to use the context object to connect to the database to retrieve the data, so what are the options?

Comment: Maybe related somehow to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485742/ef-code-first-recreate-database-if-model-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code first doesn't support database migration / evolution yet. If you want to do incremental DB development use model first (EDMX) with DbContext Generator T4 template and [Entity designer database generation](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87) pack which is able to create diff. scripts from the model.

Answer (score 2):

[From Scott Gu:](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)

> Importantly, though, the auto-create
>   database option is just an option – it
>   is definitely not required.  If you
>   point your connection-string at an
>   existing database then EF “code first”
>   will not try and create one
>   automatically. The auto-recreate
>   option also won’t be enabled unless
>   you explicitly want EF to do this – so
>   you don’t need to worry about it
>   dropping and recreating your database
>   unless you’ve explicitly indicated you
>   want it to do so.

Comment: But this also imply that I will manually have to edit the database scheme to match the mode again right?

Comment: Probably... to be honest, I didn't think that was as big of a deal, but it looks like code first won't keep the model & db in sync w/o rewriting the DB